# Meaning of "not so apt to be solicited"

Tags: idioms, archaicisms

In 1852, a US senator complained that the head of the census bureau presented medical statistics to congress when he lacked expertise in the field. When the bureau chief told the senator of the experts he consulted on the statistics, the senator said he "did not wish to be instructed" on the subject. The census man replied he only wished to "explain as to the misapprehension" the senator was under regarding the source of the statistics. The senator repeated his wish not to be "instructed." The census chief then remarked to the senator that "where information was needed, it was not so apt to be solicited." Whereupon the senator punched him in the face.

How would I rewrite the "not so apt" line for the modern reader?

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrite for the modern reader"? It sounds perfectly clear and very well phrased to me. I don't understand why you'd want to change it. It's a great line!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question doesn't look on-topic, You need to elaborate on why you think the expression is not suitable based on your own research. Otherwise, It could be closed as off-topic. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink."  [punch].

Comment: "ignorance often resists instruction"--for the whole quote.

Answer (score 1):

When information was needed - it was not likely to be asked for.

Comment: I agree with you. "Likely" is much more apt than "apt." Don